# Using NodaTime with a .NET 7.0 project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nodatime

I have ASP.NET Core project that needs to be migrated from .NET 6.0 to.NET 7.0 and it is using NodaTime. Is there a NodaTime that is compatible with .NET Core 7.0?

Comment: Have you tried and run into problems? I'd expect it to be absolutely fine unless there's some breaking change in .NET 7 that I'm unaware of. In general, libraries which target earlier versions of .NET, .NET Core or .NET Standard should be compatible with later versions.

Comment: `NodaTime` has no compatibility issue while migrating from  `.NET 6.0 to.NET 7.0` so far. If you still encounter any issue, please feel free to share.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a NodaTime that is compatible with .NET Core 7.0?

All recent versions are. As of version 3.1.0, Noda Time targets .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET 6.0 (the latter for the sake of `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly`). There should be no reason for it not to work fine with .NET 7.0.